# Swift: create two objects each of them inside another

Tags: ios, oop, object, swift3, xcode8

I developed an iOS app which have two objects, each of one inside another, as below:
first one:

```
class OfferItem
 {
var _id : Int? = 0
var _OfferId : Int? = 0
var _ItemId : Int? = 0
var _Discount : Int? = 0
var _item = Item()
..
functions()
}
```

and 2nd one:

```
    class Item
    {

        var _id : Int! = 0
        var _RateCount : Int? = 0   
        var _Offer = OfferItem() 
         ..
    functions()
}
```

How to resolve that in such away where I can call each object in another?

Comment: Its a warning or an error?

Comment: The error is not related to the code in the question. And this is Swift: No leading underscores and variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: It's a run time error

Comment: How to resolve the process of creating two objects that each one of them inside the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must read about references in **Swift**. [Automatic Reference Counting link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

Here is your example:

```
class OfferItem {
  var id: Int?
  var discount: Int?
  var item: Item!

  init(id: Int? = nil, discount: Int? = nil, itemId: Int, itemRateCount: Int) {
    self.id = id
    self.discount = discount
    self.item = Item(id: itemId, rateCount: itemRateCount, offer: self)
  }

}


class Item {
  var id = 0
  var rateCount = 0
  unowned var offer: OfferItem

  init(id: Int, rateCount: Int, offer: OfferItem) {
    self.id = id
    self.rateCount = rateCount
    self.offer = offer
  }
}


var offerItem = OfferItem(id: 10, discount: 2, itemId: 1, itemRateCount: 20)

print(offerItem.item.id, offerItem.item.offer.id)
```

Result: *1* *Optional(10)*

I hope to help you with my answer above!